# How to require revision logging for certain users

Tags: 7, workflows, nodes

In Drupal 7, if a specific role modifies any content, I want to require that the user add message explaining the changes.  How can this be accomplished, either through an existing contrib module or custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a Enforce Revision Log that will do this https://www.drupal.org/project/enforce_revlog module